# utPLSQL and existing data?

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, plsql

I'm struggling to deploy utPLSQL to improve quality in my current project. The problem is that there are currently almost 1000 database tables and nearly 800 PL/SQL packages. Also I'm very new using utPLSQL framework but have some experience in SQL and PL/SQL.

I cannot rely on existing data to stay the same during and between test runs in order to produce same test results since there are dozens of developers changing the data constantly. What I'm looking for is to create temporary test tables in the tester schema based on existing production tables, fill them with test data and make PL/SQL code to use those test tables when running tests. Is it even possible? If not, what approach should I use?

I've been reading **Kevin McCormack**'s article [Continuous Integration with Oracle PL/SQL, utPLSQL and Hudson](http://www.theserverlabs.com/blog/2009/05/18/continuous-integration-with-oracle-plsql-utplsql-and-hudson/) but the problem is I cannot spend too much time for reading and trying to find solution before the idea of using utPLSQL framework will be mothballed by the organization I'm working for.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Bob. Your answer was very helpful.

Comment: @Bob has the right approach. You can also use the `setup` and `teardown` procedures to help keep this data work separate from the actual test code

Comment: It sounds like your organization uses servers for development instead of workstations.  Until developers have their own private database and the code "lives" in version-controlled files, there's probably no good way to add unit testing.  Bob's answer might help, but in many systems it's impossible to do meaningful testing inside a single transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using utPLSQL I have each test create any data it needs, execute the test against the created data, then roll back the transaction at the end which effectively removes the test data from the database. This takes extra time because I have to figure out what data actually needs to be created, but ensures that the data exists when it's needed and doesn't hang around when it isn't needed - and the tests don't count on data which may or may not exist. YMMV.